# Docker - Linking Cassandra container with another container

Tags: python, docker, cassandra

Hi there :) I'm new to Docker,! I have been trying to create a Cassandra-based container on Ubuntu 16.04 and link to it from another container on the same machine. The goal is to access the database using Python's Cassandra driver from the second container.

I am creating the Cassandra driver as follows, exposing all ports:

```
docker run -d --name some-cassandra -p 7000:7000 -p 7001:7001 -p 7199:7199 -p 9042:9042 -p 9160:9160 --rm -t cassandra
```

And linking with another container as follows:

```
run --name python-container \
--volume=$HOME/cassandra/output:/output --rm \
--link some-cassandra:cassandra \
-d custom-cassandra:latest
```

custom-cassandra is a custom Docker image that mainly installs Python, pip and cassandra-driver. Then, I am connecting to the second container using:

```
docker exec -it python-container python
```

However, the following code fails:

```
from cassandra import ConsistencyLevel, OperationTimedOut, WriteTimeout
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.query import SimpleStatement
session = Cluster(['localhost']).connect()
```

with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 1247, in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connect
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 1283, in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connect
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 1270, in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connect
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 2773, in cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection.connect
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 2816, in cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection._reconnect_internal
cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused"), '::1': error(99, "Tried connecting to [('::1', 9042, 0, 0)]. Last error: Cannot assign requested address")})
```

What is it that I am doing wrong with the linking please?

Comment: If you try with some-cassandra instead of localhost in your python script?

Comment: @Mathias It worked!! Thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate it ^^

Comment: Perfect, your welcome. Glad to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use instead of `localhost` the name of the container (`some-cassandra`) in your pyton script. `localhost` inside a container referes always to the container itself and not the host machine.

---

Furthermore instead of creating containers one by one, you can also use docker-compose to start multiple containers together. Here a link for more information: https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/#step-2-create-a-dockerfile

Basically you build an docker image with your application, create a docker-compose file and start it.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  casandra:
    image: cassandra:latest

  myapp:
    image: mypythonapplicaiton
    depends_on:
      - casandra
    environment:
      - CASSANDRA_HOST=cassandra
```

(your applicaiton can get the cassandra host from the environment variable `CASSANDRA_HOST` or however you call the variable)

Afterwards start it with `docker-compose up -d`.